# How to remove duplicates from a list of objects based on another list of objects?

Tags: python

I have 2 lists of objects:

For example:

```
class Object1:
    def __init__(self, id):
         self.id = id

Object1List = []
Object1List.append(Object1("id", 1))
Object1List.append(Object1("id", 2))
Object1List.append(Object1("id", 3))

class Object2:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

Object2List = []
Object2List.append(Object2("id", 3))
Object2List.append(Object2("id", 4))
Object2List.append(Object2("id", 5))
Object2List.append(Object2("id", 6))
```

How do I remove any objects from `Object1List` with the same `id` as one in `Object2List`?

Comment: What have you tried, and what unexpected result did you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've added `__repr__` methods to the classes such that printing is more meaningful (you don't have to do that):

```
class Object1:
    def __init__(self, id):
         self.id = id
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Object1(id={self.id})"

class Object2:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Object2(id={self.id})"
```

Your lists are:

```
Object1List = [Object1(id=n) for n in range(1, 4)]
Object2List = [Object2(id=n) for n in range(3, 7)]
```

```
[Object1(id=1), Object1(id=2), Object1(id=3)]
[Object2(id=3), Object2(id=4), Object2(id=5), Object2(id=6)]
```

To get the expected output you could first collect the `id`s of `Object2List` in a set, and then filter out the corresponding `Object1List` objects with a list comprehension (set-lookup is very efficient):

```
Object2ListIDs = {obj.id for obj in Object2List}
Object1ListNew = [obj for obj in Object1List if obj.id not in Object2ListIDs]
```

Result:

```
[Object1(id=1), Object1(id=2)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a function with like:

```
def remove_replicates(list1, list2):
    temp = list1
    for obj1 in list1:
        for obj2 in list2:
            if obj1.id == obj2.id:
                temp.remove(obj1)
                continue
    
    return temp
```

Comment: Be careful when [removing items from a list while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6260089/2745495).

Comment: I'm just finding that out, if list 1 only has 1 item in, the code above errors. Is there any way to guard against that other than an if statement checking `len`

Comment: @WhatTheWhat See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1207406/2745495

Comment: presumable this only works if the objects are the same, what if they are different?

Comment: @ginomempin Yep you're right. I just updated the code. (Not the most efficient way though)

Comment: `temp = list1` does not make a copy of the list. It just gives it a new name, but it's the same list. See [How do I clone a list so that it doesn't change unexpectedly after assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612802/2745495). See the link I already shared above on how to correctly remove while iterating.